# Low-Resource Single-User XMPP Daemon

Tags: xmpp

Does anyone know a jabber daemon which is very fast and uses few resources for just a single-user? The daemon should be configured to only accept one user. It does not need to scale well for a lot of users.

Comment: See also on *Software Recommendations SE*: [Hassle-free XMPP server for single user](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/574/60)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience has shown me that ejabberd hasn't been designed to be lightweight. At least not without heavy modification of it.
[Prosody](http://prosody.im) on the other hand has been designed to be lightweight and runs perfectly in low resource environments like on home network routers or VPS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/). It's quite lightweight, and can certainly be configured to only accept a single user.